# Django - HTML form does not submit (request.POST.get(...) is empty)

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a HTML form like this:

```
<form action="/submit_prform/" method="POST" class="prform" id="prform" name="prform">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="node" name="node_1" id="node_1">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" class="node_index" name="node_index">
        <label for="node_name_1">Node 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="node_name" name="node_name" id="node_name_1">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" class="target_count">
        <div class="node_targets" name="node_targets">
            <div class="target" name="target_1_1">
                <label class="target_class_label" for="target_name">Target 1:</label>
                <input type="text" class="target_name">
                <label for="value">Value</label>
                <input type="text" class="value">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="add_target">Add target</button>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

The button is to add more target fields using Javascript.

My urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^submit_prform/',pagerank_django.views.submit_prform),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include("pagerank_django.urls")),
]
```

And my views.py looks like this:

```
def submit_prform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = request.POST.get("prform")
        print(request, form)
        return render(request, "pagerank_django/index.html", {})

def index(request):
    return render(request, "pagerank_django/index.html", {})
```

I am unable to get the form I submit in my view function, it prints the following:

```
[20/May/2016 11:29:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3593
[20/May/2016 11:29:36] "GET /static/pagerank_django/pagerank.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
<WSGIRequest: POST '/submit_prform/'> None
[20/May/2016 11:29:37] "POST /submit_prform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3593
```

How can I access the form I submit in views.py?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form = request.POST.get("prform")
```

This is empty because you don't have a field called prform in your form!

Since you are using django, why don't put the power of Django to good use.

Use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/).

> Unless you’re planning to build websites and applications that do
>   nothing but publish content, and don’t accept input from your
>   visitors, you’re going to need to understand and use forms.
>
> Django provides a range of tools and libraries to help you build forms
>   to accept input from site visitors, and then process and respond to
>   the input.